# Collect the number of labels under blogger/blogspot in javascript?

Tags: javascript, blogger, label, blogspot

I would like to know, if it's possible to collect the number of labels for each of the labels?

In fact, in my menu, I put the label names and I would like to add beside their numbers. For example, 5 items from my bolg have the wording "journey" in common and I would put in my menu next to the wording "journey" (5) automatically.

I was given an start of idea :

1/ Establish two tables with all labels in a Label widget. The first table with the label names and the second table with the numbers of articles :

*labelName=["Label1","Label2","Label3"];
labelCount=[10,27,6];*

Implementation :

`<script>
  labelName=<b:eval expr='data:labels map (l => l.name)'/>;
  labelCount=<b:eval expr='data:labels map (l => l.count)'/>;
</script>`

2/ from the Blog widget, extract a table containing only the wording of post

*postLabelName=["Label1","Label2"];*

Implementation :

`<script>
  postLabelName =<b:eval expr='data:post.labels map (l => l.name)'/>;
</script>`

From these variables, write a script at the end of the blog comparing the various tables.

Can you help me ? Thanks in advance.